# Native JSON object support on mobile browsers

Tags: json, mobile, webview, mobile-safari, mobile-webkit

I want to use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to do some work on mobile browsers such as mobile safari on iOS and Webkit browsers on android and also the WebView on both platforms. I want to know the compatibility.

PS: I tested the functionality on android 2.1 and iOS 3.2 and they both support.

Comment: I am going to test this myself and get back with an answer. I hate when people ask questions like this that can be solved with a little homework and leave the questions unanswered. This one is fresh so i guess thats ok ;) . No more stackoverflow orphans people! If you find an answer come back and let us know. I need to know the answer to this so ill test it in a mobile browser and post the results.

Comment: Tested JSON.parse/stringify on iPad 2 / iOS 5.1. It works.

Comment: It seemed that it is a firefox's bug.

Answer (score 7):

This site offers great tables of compatibility for lots of functionalities.
Check the JSON mobile support here:
http://caniuse.com/json

Hope you find it useful.
Cheers.